# Android voicemail GUI app

Tags: android, voicemail

I dislike listening to voicemail, waiting for messages to finish, trying to call some of them, deleting others, finding out who called & when, etc...

I would like an app to display this sort of info visually, and preferably without requiring me to get a new (voicemail) number.

I would even be willing to code it myself, but I am afraid that it can't be done because different operators will have different APIs (if any) to their voicemail.

Does such an app exist, preferably gratis? Alternatively, could it be developed?

Comment: I suspect this will depend on a) Whether the service provider has an API and b) whether there is a common API between service providers plus of course if they give access to that API.

Comment: See: http://www.mobileindustryreview.com/2011/01/visual-voicemail-a-super-example-of-britains-lazy-inept-innovation-less-mobile-operators.html for a lovely discussion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A lot depends on which Operator you are using and in which country - the iPhone users have had a similar App available for years but in the UK only O2 had rolled it out at one point - after several years.

Currently on O2 in the UK there is [TU Go](http://www.o2.co.uk/apps/tu-go) which adds a lot including Voicemail as text but some operators don't have such a service enabled.